# receiving error 500.19 when attempting to launch website

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

We are moving our websites from a 2008 r2 server running IIS 7.5. The first program I moved over was asp.net core when attempting to run it I get the error HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error with the error code 0x8007000d. This starts my internet search unfortunately I don't have a config error which would narrow down the search quite a bit and none of the solutions I found worked. This code works on the old server just fine and I don't have anything in my code specifying the cpu so it not set to 32 bit.

Everything I have tried points me in the direction that the web.config file cannot be accessed. one of the reasons I say that is when I try to open configuration editor I receive the error the data is invalid (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000D) below is the web.config that I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Brochure_Fulfillment.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: e089189f-00f3-48ee-9532-1c03776dad6a-->
```

Comment: Obvious things: Have you installed the ASP.NET Core Hosting bundle? Have you restarted the server afterwards? Then, if you're still having issues, open a command prompt to the published app folder on your server and run `dotnet MyApp.dll`. Report any exceptions that are raised.

Comment: Thanks for the help in a moment of frustration I reinstalled the hosting bundle and it worked.

Comment: You might post what you learned as an answer and accept it. Next time, you might find a diagnostic tool helpful https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html